# Android worker thread not exiting

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread derived from the `Thread` class inside a small test app.  I start it by using its `start()` method.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to terminate when I stop the app's execution from within Eclipse by using the stop button.  The only way I can get the thread to terminate is by uninstalling the app.

Is this normal?  Can I get the app to completely stop and exit memory by stopping it in the debugger or do I always have to use a "clean" way to exit from within the app itself?

Comment: Yep; that's normal. Just because your Activity thread exited, that doesn't mean other threads will be killed. This isn't an Android-specific issue either; if you use threads in a Java app, you may have cleanup issues when the main thread exits.

Comment: @EdwardFalk So, is there a better solution than uninstalling the app when killing it from the debugger?  Even 'force stop' from the device settings does not seem to work.

Comment: Yes, see Aswin's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it cleanly by stopping the Thread in onDestroy() or onStop() of the Activity. To stop the Thread, you can keep a flag in the Thread and turn it on when you want to stop.

```
public void stopRunning() {
    stopped = true;
}

public void run() {
    while (!stopped) {
        try {
            // Do something
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stopping the app from Eclipse doesn't stop the app from running on the device, it merely severs the connection between Eclipse and the app.

The thread, like any Java thread, can potentially keep executing as long as the JVM is active. Note that, even if your app is hidden in the background, this also does not mean the JVM has been stopped. (Although it should stop if you restart your phone or force kill the app.)  A solution like Aswins is best, although often you're going to want to stop in onPause, especially if the Thread maintains a reference to the Activity.

Comment: This is pretty much the right answer. Note that 'stopped' should be declared volatile.

Comment: One note: there's no guarantee that onDestroy() will actually get called, but it doesn't matter because in that case, the system will have killed your entire application, threads and all.

Comment: This looks like how to do it under normal operating conditions.  How can I kill all threads from the debugger in Eclipse?